# Optionally loading template in ngRoute

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

I have two templates as `a.html` and `b.html`. Now `a.html` is for logged in users and `b.html` for people who are not. Authentication is through an api running on a separate sub-domain. Now i have a call that tells whether a person is authenticated in scope.

How can i optionally load templates based on that. One method is i load `b.html` and conditionally redirect authenticated users but that is not something i am looking for.
Here is my ngRoute codes

```
var app = angular.module('app',['ngRoute']);

app.config(function ($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $routeProvider
    .when('/',{
            templateUrl : '/templates/b.html',
            controller  : 'mainController'
        })
    .otherwise({
        templateUrl : 'templates/404.html',
        controller  : 'mainController'
    });
});

app.controller('mainController', function($scope) {

});
```

Comment: Is conditional routing applicable? Or Is it necessary for u that these two templates MUST share the same path (same url in browser address bar) ?

Comment: Url must be the same. Both on "/". I didn't get what you mean by conditional routing. FYI the angular app is jekyll so no changes there. Api on subdomain is django

Comment: Well, If i understood u right, you required that you don't want to load `b.html` first and then redirect, but you are doing the authentication via an api. Does it mean you want to somehow keep your angular app from displaying or changing route until the authentication is completed?

Comment: @MMhunter yes. It send token to server and gets the state of the user. If he is authenticated then a.html else b.html :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code could somehow satisfy your requirements but it is in fact a bit tricky since i used ng-include instead of directly setting the templateUrl.

The key is to use the [resolve param in $routeProvider](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider). when u pass a $promise as a member in it, the router will wait for them all to be resolved.

```
 app.controller('MainController', ['$scope','loadedTemplate',function ($scope,loadedTemplate) {
     //inject the template from the resolve function
     $scope.loadedTemplate = loadedTemplate;
 }]);

//Service to keep loginStatus
app.factory("loginService",function(){
    return {
      isLogin:false,
      loginStatusFetched:false,
  }
})

app.config(['$routeProvider',function ($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider.
    when('/', {
        template: "<div ng-include='loadedTemplate'></div>",
        controller: 'MainController',
        resolve:{
          loadedTemplate:function($q, $http,$route,loginService) {
              console.log("fetching login status");
              if(loginService.loginStatusFeteched){
                    if(loginService.isLogin){
                          return "a.html"
                    }
                    else{
                            return "b.html"
                    }
              }
              console.log("fetching remote authentication");
              var deferred = $q.defer();
              $http({method: 'GET', url: 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1'})
                  .success(function(data) {

                      //update the login status here
                      loginService.loginStatusFeteched = true;
                      loginService.isLogin = true;
                      if(loginService.isLogin){
                        deferred.resolve("a.html");
                      }
                      else{
                        deferred.resolve("b.html");
                      }
                  })
                  .error(function(data){
                  //error
                      deferred.resolve("b.html");
                  });

              return deferred.promise;  
          }
        }
    })
}]);
```

I attempted to achieve what u required by setting the templateUrl to a function, but it only takes routeParams, and when the $promise in `resolve` get resolved, this function has already been executed and there is no way to change the current loaded template.

There is still other choices that you can try. You may use `angular-ui-router` instead of `ng-route` to handle state changes, in which u may set child states and present them with the same url conditionally.

But I believe there might be better ways to achieve what you want. If anyone has any better solution, please let me know.